# how to Fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java Hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package com.candidjava;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class AddStudent {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory1;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args[0] != null || args[1] != null || args[2] != null) {// begin if
                                                                    // A
            String name = args[0];
            String name1 = args[0];
            String degree = args[1];
            String phone = args[2];
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
            System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);

            if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals("") || phone.equals(""))) {
                System.out.println("All informations are Required");
            } else {

                try {// begin try

                    sessionFactory1 = new Configuration().configure(
                            "com\\xml\\student1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("mathan");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.err
                            .println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."
                                    + e);

                }

                Session s1 = sessionFactory1.openSession();
                Transaction tx1 = s1.beginTransaction();
                Student1 stu1 = new Student1();
                stu1.setName(name1);
                s1.save(stu1);
                tx1.commit();
                System.out.println("Added to mysql Database");
                if (s1 != null)
                    s1.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is MY code i Dont know where am Doing Mistake But when I run this application then Exception comes i am creating Hibernate sample application

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.candidjava.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:15)
 This Exception comes i Dont know how to Fix it please help ...

Answer (score 2):

One of the problem maybe that you need to use && in the following condition:

```
    if (args[0] != null || args[1] != null || args[2] != null) {// begin if
```

cHange it to:

```
    if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null && args[2] != null) {
```

Also the following check has the same logical problem:

```
        if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals("") || phone.equals(""))) {
```

should be :

```
        if ((name.equals("") && degree.equals("") && phone.equals(""))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not passing all the arguments make your condition with logical and not or

```
 if (args[0] != null && args[1] != null && args[2] != null) {
```

And, you are on wrong track with  configuring `configure`

```
student1.cfg.xml
```

I believe the above file is the mapping xml file for `Student` pojo.

Not the hibernate `configuration` file.

While dealing with hibernate read the `properties` from `hibernate.cfg.xml` file not   from args.

[Hibernate Configuration Official Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do validation at once

```
package com.candidjava;
```

import java.sql.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class AddStudent {

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory1;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     if ((name.equals("") && degree.equals("") && phone.equals(""))) {
            System.out.println("All informations are Required");
        } else {

        String name = args[0];
        String name1 = args[0];
        String degree = args[1];
        String phone = args[2];
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
        System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);   

            try {// begin try

                sessionFactory1 = new Configuration().configure(
                        "com\\xml\\student1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("mathan");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.err
                        .println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."
                                + e);

            }

            Session s1 = sessionFactory1.openSession();
            Transaction tx1 = s1.beginTransaction();
            Student1 stu1 = new Student1();
            stu1.setName(name1);
            s1.save(stu1);
            tx1.commit();
            System.out.println("Added to mysql Database");
            if (s1 != null)
                s1.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial has been rewritten in candidjava website, try this new [hibernate annotations](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Basic-getting-started-example-using-hibernate-annotation.htm) example

Comment: please include content in your answer