# how to handle java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in java

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package com.candidjava;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class AddStudent {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory1;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args[0] != null || args[1] != null || args[2] != null) {// begin if
                                                                    // A
            String name = args[0];
            // String name1=args[0];
            String degree = args[1];
            String phone = args[2];
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
            System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);

            if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals("") || phone.equals(""))) {
                System.out.println("All informations are Required");
            } else {

                try {// begin try

                    sessionFactory1 = new Configuration().configure(
                            "com\\xml\\student1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("mathan");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.err
                            .println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."
                                    + e);

                }

                Session s1 = sessionFactory1.openSession();
                Transaction tx1 = s1.beginTransaction();
                Student1 stu1 = new Student1();
                // stu1.setName(name1);
                s1.save(stu1);
                tx1.commit();
                System.out.println("Added to mysql Database");
                if (s1 != null)
                    s1.close();
            }
        }// end of if A
    }// end of method
}// end of class
```

This is my code  am creating sample Hibernate application Using Eclipsed BUt I dont know why this Exception is coming my code :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.candidjava.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:17)
```

Please help me why this `Exception` while I have write simple Hinter application using Java code

Comment: Why you posted again ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151885/how-to-fix-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-java-hibernate-applicatio/19151914#19151914

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ same question

Answer (score 3):

Try using something more like....

```
if (args.length == 3) {...
```

To determine if the correct number of arguments are available.  Once you've done that, you can the determine if there values are valid (ie `!= null`)

Comment: +1 too quick and correct!

Comment: @JunedAhsan That makes a change :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ironically Juned gave an answer already few min back :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151885/how-to-fix-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-java-hibernate-applicatio/19151914#19151914

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ But, as far as I can tell, neither actually answer why the OP is getting an index out of bounds exception...IMHO - Not that is a reason to double post mind you...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's the reason I gave you an upvote dear :) . But repost should be closed. And I believe you didn't see that post previously.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Either question should be closed :P (ps - The advice given the other question was still good ;))